# Install error — occurring for one specific device

Tags: android

My `.apk` file is confirmed working, however for users of the Motorola Milestone (which runs the same android version 2.0 and up) they receive the error upon attempt to install.

I've googled and searched through the other questions here.

The error seems to normally only appear if you did something wrong in the signing wizard or renamed the file.

Is it possible that some kind of software difference on the OS build on these Milestones is preventing the install?

Comment: Did you try asking on MotoDev?  What permissions are required?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that it is actually happening because my manifest file is saying the min API level required is 6 (2.0.1) which milestone users don't have yet officially, they are still on 5, regular 2.0. I put up another build that only sets 5 as the min, as I am using nothing from 2.0.1 or 2.1 yet. I will report back if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the manifest was declaring it as requiring 2.0.1. I had a milestone user try a build that only specified API 5 as the min and set API 6 as the targetted. They were able to install. Milestone still only has 2.0 at the moment so it was a bit of a circumstantial oversight on my part. Very silly of me.