# Error to install my android app

Tags: android, installation

My problem is that I finished my android app, and I want to try in a real device. So I auto send me an email with the .apk. But then when I proceed to install the .apk in the device, it give me an error:

Parse error
there has been a problem for analysing the packet

(I turn on the settings-applications-> unknown user) so that it's not the problem

I tried on another device and have the same problem, so I decided to try another app that I have, an the same problem....

Anyone have any idea of what happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112876/install-error-problem-parsing-the-package-occurring-for-one-specific-device

Comment: The most strange think is that I create a helloworld example, an I try to install it, an the same problem ocurred. So mayby the problem is my laptop? or my SO (Linux, ubuntu 11.1)

Answer (score 0):

There are differenct methods;
1.If you want to install the apk thru mail then try use Gmail client in android or opera browser and download the app first on sdcard and then open and install it.

1. Put the apk on sdcard and then scan the apk thru AndroidZip app or other app which wil scan the apk on sdcard and install it.
2. Connect ur device to eclipse and directly run the app to device

Comment: Okie is there app which is already install with same name or package? if yes then uninstall that apk and install new one..

Answer (score 0):

Sticko, if you are using the Gmail app on Android phone, sorry to say you cannot install directly. However what you should instead be doing is take a USB cable/bluetooth and transfer the app to your SD card. Then run it from there (just click on it)

Else, if you want to debug the code on the device, then as Maneesh put it, you'll have to connect it with eclipse for remote debugging on device.

Comment: It's still not running, I try to do what you say, an the same error.
I try to do with the adb, but it doesn't find my device (I modify the 51-android..... for my device and this stuff) so I couldn't try with that. 

But I think the problem is not with my movil, because I try with another one, and I still have the same problem. Maybe it's something wrong with my eclipse...

Comment: Have you signed your app ? One common problem people do is they rename the apk file after signing it. That is also known to cause a problem. If you still are stuck, best way is to connect your phone to eclipse, open the logcat view and keep looking at the live stack trace..

Comment: Okie is there app which is already install with same name or package? if yes then uninstall that apk and install new one..

Comment: I think it is not the problem, because I try to install an example of andorid (com.example.HelloWorld) and doesn't work too. And I have other apps that I did, and have the same problem.

Can you explain me how to connect the movil with explise? because I try with the adb and doesn't find my device. 

thanks!

Comment: I solve it! the problem was that in my android manifest, I have this line <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> and my android version in  my device is less tan 2.3.3 so I put <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> and It works!